# Fixing bad git state (trying to reapply stashed changes w/ conflict)

Tags: git

My particular issue is a bit more complicated than regular stash apply, which can be remedied by committing the merge conflict. Here are the events leading up to the current state:

- I created a feature branch for my own work (i.e. `my_branch`) and did some work there
- Another coworker created separate feature branch for his closely related backend work (`branch_2`)
- I applied changes from his branch via `git pull origin branch_2` with the intent of discarding them when done
- I made more changes to my own work and committed them (without committing `branch_2` files)
- I stashed uncommitted `branch_2` changes when I had to switch gears to a higher priority task
- I came back to the branch, did `git pull origin master` to bring my branch up to date
- I attempted to `git stash apply` but was met with a merge conflict
- To resolve the conflict, git wanted me to commit the file (file from `branch_2` that I specifically plan to discard after I'm done implementing/testing my functionality)
- I instead decided to do `git checkout -- .` to blow away `branch_2` changes, figuring I'd just reapply them, but I realized later that `git pull origin branch_2` won't work again since the command is already in my history, and git doesn't realize that I effectively undid it

**Now I need to get to the same state I was in step 3 above but with latest master pulled in. What is the cleanest way to get the repo to that state?**

From what I understand, `git cherry-pick` manually changes from `branch_2` would have the undesired side-effect of having git still think `branch_2` has already been merged into my branch and may result in merge issues later when both of our branches go to master?

Could I achieve what I want via `git revert` of original commit that pulled `branch_2` in or are there other side-effects?

Should I rollback all the way to step 1, pull master, cherry-pick my later commits and then apply my coworker's changes again?

Comment: I am having trouble following (1) which branch you made the changes that you care about on, and (2) whether work has progressed on both my_branch and branch_2 locally (& origin/branch_2?). It sounds a problem you might have is you were not able to separate your changes into semantically independent commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for the "cleanest" way, and there really is no such thing: cleanliness, in this case, is in the eye of the beholder, so to speak.  The main thing, though, is to stop thinking in terms of *branches* and *files* because those aren't really what Git is about, or deals with.  You should think of this in terms of *commits*, with branch names merely being used to *find* the various commits that you and others will make.

Keep in mind that each *name* is unique to its own particular Git repository.  What get shared are the commits.  What matters, then, are the commits, and their hash IDs.

This is a bit problematic, because hash IDs are unpredictable, and also big and ugly and impossible to remember.  But each commit gets its own unique hash ID, and that hash ID then means *that* commit, forever.  You plug two Git repositories into each other temporarily, using `git fetch` or `git push`, and have one transfer some commits into the other: they come with their hash IDs, and all Gits everywhere agree that *those* hash IDs are reserved to *those* commits.

Humans being human, we don't use the hash IDs.  We use the names.  But each name just holds one hash ID.  The tricky part is that the hash ID value of any given branch name will *change* over time, and *your* Git's names—or rather, the hash ID values inside those names—won't match some other Git's, at least not all the time.

Meanwhile, every commit stores a list of *previous* commit hash IDs.  Most commits store only one previous hash ID.  The stored hash ID, in some commit, is the commit's *parent*—or, for a merge commit, its parents, plural.  The only commits that have *no* parent, that don't list any earlier commits, are *root* commits.  The first commit you ever make, in a new empty repository, is a root commit.

I find that it helps a great deal to *draw* the commits.  (Git can do this for you, with `git log --graph`, which is particularly useful when combined with `--oneline`.)  To do this on StackOverflow, I like to give each commit a single letter "name" in place of its actual hash name, so that we can see the commits and the order they're made.

Let's start with a very simple (new) repository with only three commits in it.  We'll call them `A`—the first commit ever made, which is a root commit—and `B` and `C`.  Since `C` is the *last* commit, it contains the hash ID of commit `B`.  Commit `B` contains the hash ID of commit `A`.  We say that `C` points to `B`, and `B` points to `A`:

```
A <-B <-C
```

We need a name—a branch name—that will remember the actual hash ID of commit `C`.  Branch names change, but commits, once made, do not change at all: the actual hash ID of `C`, whatever it is, means *that* `C` with its embedded arrow pointing to `B`.  None of this can ever change, so we can just draw the connections between commits as lines, as long as we remember that they actually point *backwards*.  We'll make the name `master` point to commit `C`, though, and keep it as an arrow as its arrow *will* change over time:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

Now let's add a new branch name, `dev`, that also points to commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, dev
```

We need a way to tell Git: *we're using the name `master`* or *we're using the name `dev`*.  Either way, we're using commit `C`, but we need to know which *name* we're using, because we are about to create a new commit `D`.  So let's attach the special name `HEAD` to one of them, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, dev (HEAD)
```

Now let's add a new commit, in the usual way.  When we run `git commit`, Git packages up whatever is in the index—a complete snapshot of all of our files—and gathers our name and email address and the current date-and-time and so on, to put into a new commit.  The new commit eventually gets written out and thereby acquires some new, unique, big ugly hash ID, but we'll just call it `D`.  The *parent* of `D` will be `C`, as that's the commit we're using:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, dev (HEAD)
       \
        D
```

but now Git will *move* the current *branch*—the one that `HEAD` is attached to—so that it points to new commit `D`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

and that's what it means to make new commits.

As we add more commits, the repository graph gets more complicated:

```
       I--J   <-- branch1
      /
...--H   <-- master
      \
       K--L   <-- branch2
```

but always, each *branch name* points to *one* commit.  Here `master` points to `H`, for instance.  That one commit is the tip of *that* branch, even if there are more commits after it.  Those other commits—after that one—are not on `master`.  Commits up through `H` are on *all three* branches, while commits `I-J` are only on `branch1`, and commits `K-L` are *only* on `branch2`.

With this in mind, let's start in on your steps:

> 1. I created a feature branch for my own work (i.e. `my_branch`) and did some work there

So you had:

```
          I--J   <-- my_branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

> 2. Another coworker created separate feature branch for his closely related backend work (`branch_2`)

Now, this didn't happen in your repository.  But presumably the co-worker shared commits up through `H` in *his* repository, and had *his* name `master` pointing to commit `H`.  He made a few commits—I'll draw two and call them `K` and `L`—and made them available to your Git (probably by `git push`-ing them to some *third*, common, repository, that your Git calls `origin`).

> 3. I applied changes from his branch via `git pull origin branch_2` with the intent of discarding them when done

OK: `git pull` is a bit of a complicated command.  It mostly just runs two other Git commands, though.  First, it runs `git fetch`.  Your `git fetch` operation did this in your own repository:

```
          I--J   <-- my_branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/branch2
```

Note that your *remote-tracking name*, `origin/branch2`, is based off the name your Git saw in the Git at `origin`, which is using a *branch name*, `branch2`, to identify commit `L`.  (These details are sometimes important, and sometimes not so much.)

The second part of `git pull`, though, is to run `git merge`.  Your Git now ran:

```
git merge -m "merge branch branch2 of <url> into my_branch" <hash-of-L>
```

The `-m` argument is computed for you by `git pull`, as is the actual hash ID of commit L.  If you did this on your own, rather than through `git pull`, you'd run:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/branch2
```

The `fetch` step would obtain the commits and set up your `origin/branch2` as before, and the `merge` step would do the same thing as `git pull`'s merge step, but with a slightly different default merge message.

This merge operation, if successful—it sounds like this one was—goes on to make a *merge commit*.  At this point, I'm going to just stop drawing in the name `master`, but it continues to point where it used to:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- my_branch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- origin/branch2
```

Note that none of your existing commits have changed!  None of your coworkers have changed either.  No existing commit can *ever* change.  All that has happened is that you have now added a *new* commit, and moved your name `my_branch` so that it points to this new merge commit.

Note that what is in `M` is a *combination* of both your work, and your coworker's work.  Git took the difference between your common starting point—commit `H`, for both of you—and your then-branch-tip `J`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
```

and then a second difference between `H` and `L`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git then *combined* these two sets of changes, applied the *combined* changes to the snapshot in `H`, and made the new snapshot `M`.

> 4. I made more changes to my own work and committed them (without committing `branch_2` files)

This is where your description goes wrong.  If you made a new commit `N` whose parent is `M`, that new commit `N` was made from whatever was in your *index* at the time.  The index started out matching commit `M`.  You then made some changes in your work-tree, used `git add` to copy the updated files into the index, and used `git commit` to create `N`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- my_branch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- origin/branch2
```

This really does have your co-worker's stuff in it.

Other possibilities include:

- having run `git merge`, the merge *failed* and you used `git merge --abort` to terminate it, leaving you with `my_branch` pointing to commit `J`, so that your new commit's parent is `J`; or
- having successfully merged, you then ran `git reset --hard HEAD^` or equivalent to discard<sup>1</sup> merge commit `M`, leaving you with `my_branch` pointing to commit `J`, so that your new commit's parent is `J`.

My guess, though, is that you made merge commit `M` and new commit `N` here (and perhaps some subsequent commits, but they won't change the picture too much).

> 5. I stashed uncommitted `branch_2` changes when I had to switch gears to a higher priority task

Here things get particularly difficult.  You're not on your own branch name `branch_2`; in fact, you don't even *have* your own name `branch_2`.  You have `origin/branch_2`, which your Git made when it picked up commits `K-L` in the diagram.  There should not, indeed *cannot*, be any "uncommitted `branch_2` changes".

At this point, the pictures that I can draw—that I have been drawing—seem to have no resemblance to what's actually going on in your repository, so I'm going to just say that what `git stash` does is make *two* commits, both of which are on *no* branch.  If you have a commit graph that looks like this:

```
...--o--o--P   <-- somebranch
```

and you have made changes to your work-tree and/or index, and for some reason don't want to use `git commit` in the usual, normal way, you can use `git stash` to run `git commit` for you.  What this will do is:

- First, commit your current index: all the files from your current commit, as they are, except for any files you have already used `git add` or `git rm` to update in the index, go into this `i` (index) commit:

  ```
  ...--o--o--P   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
             |
             i
  ```

  The parent of commit `i` is `P`, so that it's easy to find `P` from `i`.
- Then, commit your current work-tree: for every file that exists in your index (and now in commit `i`), `git add` each file from the work-tree, so that the index copy matches the work-tree copy.  (If the work-tree copy is removed from the work-tree, this removes the copy of the file from the index too, at this point.)  The stash code builds a new commit `w` (for work-tree) whose parent commit is `i`, and whose other parent commit is `P`.  That is, `w` *is* a merge commit.  It should not be used *as* a merge commit, but inside Git, it is a merge commit.  This makes it easy to find both `i` and `P` from `w`:

  ```
  ...--o--o--P   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
             |\
             i-w
  ```
- Sets the special reference name `refs/stash` to remember the hash ID of commit `w`:

  ```
  ...--o--o--P   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
             |\
             i-w   <-- refs/stash
  ```
- Does a `git reset --hard` to restore the index and your work-tree so that they match commit `P`.

Note that `HEAD` never changes at all here: it was attached to some branch, and still is attached to that same branch.  No existing commit changes—none *can* of course—and the current branch name remains pointing to its current commit.  Git has merely made two *new* commits, one with whatever was in your index—even if the staging area completely matches commit `P`—and a second one with whatever was in your work-tree (tracked files only; this commit was based on the index that was used to make commit `i`).

#### Cherry-pick and revert

What `git cherry-pick` does is to *copy* a commit.  To do so, it uses the fact that most commits have exactly one parent:

```
...--o--P--C--o--...--o   <-- branch1
  \
   o--o--T   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

Here, `P` and `C` are a parent-and-child pair.  If we compare the parent's snapshot in `P` to the child's in `C`, we'll see what *changed* between `P` and `C`.

If we're on branch `branch2` whose tip commit is `T`, and we run `git cherry-pick C`, Git will attempt to copy those changes.  In reality, what it does is run a `git merge` with the merge base set to commit `P`.  The *what we changed* or `--ours` changes are the result of a diff of commit `P` vs commit `T`.  The *what they changed* or `--theirs` changes are the result of a diff of commit `P` vs commit `C`, i.e., what they changed in that one commit.  Combining these two sets of changes, and applying the combined changes to the snapshot in `T`, gives Git the new snapshot to write out for a new commit `U`:

```
...--o--P--C--o--...--o   <-- branch1
  \
   o--o--T--U   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

New commit `U` becomes the tip of `branch2`, with `branch1` unchanged.  Running `git diff <hash-of-P> <hash-of-C>` and `git diff <hash-of-T> <hash-of-U>` will generally mostly the same thing, except that if the diff from `P` to `T` included some of the same changes as the diff from `P` to `C`, the diff from `T` to `U` will omit those changes: they were already present in `T`.

What `git revert` does is actually the same thing as cherry-pick, except that the parent-and-child setup going into the merge is deliberately reversed.  That is, given the above drawing, Git will run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-C> <hash-of-T>   # what we changed
```

which is *almost* the same as for cherry-pick—Git's just using `C` instead of `P` here—and then run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-C> <hash-of-P>   # what they changed
```

which is the reverse of what Git did for cherry-pick.  By comparing `C`-vs-`P` instead of `P`-vs-`C`, the "what they changed" difference will *back out* their change.  So this makes more sense if the graph actually goes like this:

```
...--o--P--C--o--...--T   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
```

Neither `git cherry-pick` nor `git revert` actually look at the graph as a whole, though.  They just have you select commit `C`, use its backwards-pointing arrow to find commit `P`, and then do the three-way merge operation.  The final commit links back only to the current commit, rather than to both commits (as a real merge would).

Comment: Thanks, this cleared up some of my questions. My confusion  stems from misunderstanding that git pull also performed a merge (I should probably just have done a fetch). What I meant by not committing `branch_2` changes is that any diffs to those files and any new files created by `branch_2` stayed in `uncommitted` state (local changed files) while I kept committing my later work, until they were blown away by `git checkout -- .`, I'm now trying to figure out the best way to "unmerge" them so I can apply them cleanly again. So can I "git revert" the `git pull origin branch_2` commit?

Comment: The odd thing is that when `git pull` runs `git merge`, you're obligated to either *finish* the merge, or abort it entirely. There is no such thing as a partial merge. The end result *should* be that you've made, in your merge commit, something in which the new files "created by `branch_2`" (this phrase is nearly meaningless: the files are in some *commits* and that is how you got them) are also in the merge commit as well as in its second parent (their commit, now in your repository, in which those files appear).

Comment: It is possible—but only you could tell us—that what you did was to `git rm --cached` the new files, or something equivalent to that, so that they now live in your work-tree and not in your commits. That makes these work-tree copies *untracked files* that are not in commits you are making now. What really matters is what is in each *commit* that you have already and will make in the future.

Comment: With that in mind, draw—or have Git or some other tool draw—a picture of the commits that you have now. For instance, run `git log --decorate --graph` or `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` (perhaps with `--all` as well). This gives you a drawing of what you have now, along with the existing branch label(s) pointing to the commits shown. Now that you have this drawing, come up with a drawing of what you'd *like* to have, keeping in mind that you can't *change* any of the existing commits, but as long as they're only in *your* Git, you can *stop using them*.

Comment: To do the latter, set a new branch name to point to any of the existing commits—such as one that comes before the `git merge` you'd like to pretend doesn't exist—and begin making new commits, whose snapshots are whatever you like (perhaps extracted as copies of existing commits for instance). The new commits will cause the new branch name to advance, so that the graph you get starting from the new name and working backwards is the graph you want.

Comment: Once you've done this—it's the hard part—you can swap the new branch name and old branch name, or just force the old branch name to point to the last commit in the new chain. Since no one but you has the *old* chain, if you `git push` the new commits somewhere and have some upstream Git remember the *new* commits, they'll never know the old commits ever existed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up creating a new branch from master and cherry-picking the changes from the problematic branch. Now the repo looks clean, and follows the same commit history without fear of breaking something else through improper rollbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can resolve your situation without following or depending on the exact order of your specific operations, which will be potentially confounding.

It sounds like `branch_2` is a coworker’s temporary feature branch which you have been “manually tracking”, and so if you had contained in separate commits your own changes that you’d like to collect, then do this: make a list of those commits, go `git checkout origin/master && git checkout -b my_branch_take2` and cherry pick those changes sequentially.

Alternatively if everything is more messed up than that, but your changes are in one section of the file system and the other changes can be ignored, then do the same thing as above but instead of cherry picking, check out the part of the tree that has your stuff from a commit on your branch that has your latest stuff into the working tree using the same  `git checkout branch —- subtree_path` trick that I haven’t really used before but which it sounds like you know how to use. ;) it’s likely that this will be more expedient compared to the other approaches. I often like to do things this way before it’s a more explicit and due to the simplicity of logic can be a less risky way to get to the right state. You’re gonna definitely want to check the diff afterward to confirm that your assumptions were correct, though.